# How to find records that are not joined with Waterline ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am using the `node.js` framework, Sails JS, and its built-in ORM Waterline for a Tinder-like project.

I can't figure how I can write my query to get records that are not joined. In my case, when a user 'likes' or 'dislikes' another user's profile, I want the liked-profile to not show up again.

How do I accomplish this? This is what I've tried so far:

```
Cat.query('select cat.* from cat left outer join vote on cat.id = vote.owner where vote.owner is null AND cat.id !='+req.session.User.id, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);
        res.send('Yes');
        console.log(results);
    });
```

Comment: How can we help you write the query without any example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, **Cat** is user profile?
So, we need profiles which:

1. Don't belong to current user (`cat.id !== req.session.User.id`)
2. Not liked or disliked by current user.

   ```
   var query = 'select cat.* ' + 
   ' from cat left join vote on' + 
     // joining votes for current user
     ' cat.id = vote.catId and vote.owner = ' + req.session.User.id +
   ' where' + 
   // filtering out the Cat with current user Id (if needed)
   ' cat.id <> ' + req.session.User.id +
   ' and' + 
   // leaving only records with empty vote id(meaning there's no corresponding vote record)
   ' vote.id is null';
   ```

Pure SQL for more crear view:

```
select cat.* from cat left join vote on 
  cat.id = vote.catId and vote.owner = :userId
where 
  cat.id <> :userId 
and
  vote.id is null
```

We selecting **all** records from **cat** table joining votes made for them by current user. And then leaving only the records where the votes are missing, and where id <> current user Id